# Django web application gives forbidden when wsgi placeed file in home directory

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I am a starter in Django world, I have searched some posts about wsgi permission issue but is did not find solution.

The wgsi file when it is placed in home directory it is not working. But if I copy this file to `/var/www/` then the application will work.
Is placing the wgsi file in document root is an security issue?

```
[root@demo conf.d]# ls -al /home/lila/wsgi/demowsgi.py
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 205 Mar 21 10:30 /home/lila/wsgi/demowsgi.py


$cat /home/lila/wsgi/demowsgi.py

import os
import sys
sys.path = ['/var/www/html/demo']+sys.path
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'demo.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application=django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Can any one advise?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in answer for many similar questions, it is usually because your home directory (ie., `/home/lila`) has permissions which prevent the user that Apache runs as from seeing inside your home directory. Simple solution is not to put it in your home directory.